# Need help with $.ajax function - How to send an associative array?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to send data using $.ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({'url': 'my.php',
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': arr,
        'success': function(response) {
                      alert(response);
                   }
});
```

The problem is that `arr` is an associative array that looks like:

```
arr['description_0'] = 'very nice picture!';
arr['tags_0'] = 'David "Nice Picture" 2010';
arr['description_1'] = 'In the pool';
arr['tags_1'] = '"April 2010" Australia';
    .                    .
    .                    .
    .                    .
```

If `my.php` looks like:

```
<?php
echo count($_POST);
?>
```

The `response` is 0.

But, if I change

```
'data': arr,
```

to

```
'data': 'a=chess&b=checkers',
```

the `response` is 2, as expected.

What should I convert `arr` to so that the data will be sent properly ?

Comment: That works just fine as is. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: by arr being 'associative array', I assume you mean a JavaScript object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're really having problems on that, try reading [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).

---

also, I've discovered, how did you initialize your `arr` variable?

you should initialize it as `var arr = {};` then pass it as `'data': arr,`. Try to look at firebug or webket's dev tools to see what data are being `post`ed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX data is really just a regular GET or POST request done "silently" by Javascript. As such, the data has to be formed as a normal GET or POST, which means it has to be in `key=value` format. Your `'data' = arr` is a value, but has no key, so PHP cannot assign it to $_POST automatically. As far as PHP is concerned, it just receives a long string of text.

You can retrieve the data by reading $HTTP_POST_RAW_DATA, if your PHP's configured to set that, or via `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, and here is a solution not mentioned in the comments so far:

```
$.ajax({
       'url': 'my.php',
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': {
                id: 1792,
                arr[description_0] : 'very nice picture!', // DON'T quote the array key
                arr[tags_0] = 'David "Nice Picture" 2010',
             },
            'success': function(response) {
                 alert(response);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to serialize to JSON and the deserialize JSON on the server:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

data: $.toJSON(arr)

Note: You do not need to quote the keys in the $.ajax({url: ..., data: ...})

Also you should really use an object as there is not an associative array in JavaScript. JavaScript arrays are intended to use numeric "keys".